# JQuery Post data from callback function

Tags: php, jquery

I want to post data from a `callback` function in jQuery:

```
// in my "index.php"
$.post('users.php', { user : the_users_name } ,function(data) {
    $('body').html(data)
}
```

In the `users.php` I want to post data to another script without loading the `users.php` like below:

```
$.post('users2.php', { date_of_birth : $(".d_of_b_div").val() }
```

Now since `users.php` is only called as a result of  `$.post` in `index.php`, it doesn't post data to `users2.php`.

How can I solve this problem? Or what am I missing out?

Comment: please elaborate your problem , it is hard to understand why is user.php and user2.php .

Comment: You can  not call ajax in `users.php`
If you want   `users.php` data to then call `users2.php` in `index.php`

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.php`

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'users.php',
  method: 'post',
  data: { user : the_users_name },
  success: function(data) {
    $('body').html(data)
  },
  complete: function() {
    // use complete callback to call users2.php
    // this is only called after success and error callbacks are executed
    $.post('users2.php', { date_of_birth : $(".d_of_b_div").val() });
  }
});
```